# Equivalent method for addChildViewController for iOS 4.0

Tags: ios

Is there an equivalent method for `addChildViewController` for iOS 4.0 and later?

edit : addChildViewController is only available for ios 5.0 an later
What i need to do : I have a view controller (A), that acts like a container. And I need to add a view controller as child of A.

Comment: There is [self addChildViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#>] till iOS 7.1. What exactly are you looking for or What exactly you want ?

Comment: If you're still supporting ios4, you're insane.

Comment: @wholegrain in case you are insane ;) the process is laid out below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it manually:

1) add a reference from the container to the child

```
@property(retain) UIViewController *child;

...

self.child = childViewController; //when you add it
```

2) add the view

```
UIView *containerView = containerViewController.view;
UIView *childView = childViewController.view;
childView.frame = containerView.bounds; //or where to place it
[containerView addSubview:childView];
```

3) forward the appearance messages like e.g. viewDidAppear from container to child

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    ...
    [child viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```